# How to randomly replace color with second specified color in gimp?

Tags: gimp

How do I replace pixels randomly in GIMP, replacing the randomly selected pixels with a specific color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways, the simplest:

- Add a layer above your layer
- Fill with required color for random pixels
- Set that layer to `Dissolve` mode
- Adjust opacity to set the ratio of replaced pixels to original pixels

[image]

If you want to repeat the process and have found an opacity that works for you, you can also just paint the original layer using the brush or bucket after putting the tool in `Dissolve` mode with the required opacity.